# Concurrency issue - Different size for same File downloaded from Multithreaded Server in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have implemented a multithreaded client/server program in Java for downloading files, in which the server can concurrently serve the file to many clients by utilizing threads.

When I test the server with a single client it works fine, but when I test with ten or more clients using a shell script then the downloaded files all have different sizes, which differs  from the actual size of the file on the server side.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

**Code for Server:**

```
public class FileSend implements Runnable {
   Socket sock;
   String pathname;

   FileSend(Socket s, String filename) {
      sock = s;
      pathname = System.getenv("HOME") + "/" + Main.spath + "/" + filename;
   }

   void send(String pathname) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
         NoSuchPaddingException, ParseException {

      try {
         byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
         OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
         //PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(os);
         BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(os, 1024);
         int i = 0;
         File fp = new File(pathname);
         RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile(fp, "r");
         long bytecount = 1024;
         ////////////////

         while ((i = ra.read(buf, 0, 1024)) != -1) {

            bytecount += 1024;
            out.write(buf, 0, i);
            out.flush();
         }
         sock.shutdownOutput();
         out.close();
         ra.close();
         sock.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {

      }
   }

   public void run() {
      try {
         try {
            try {
               try {
                  send(this.pathname);
               } catch (ParseException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(FileSend.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                        null, ex);
               }
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(FileSend.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                     null, ex);
            }
         } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileSend.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                  ex);
         }
      } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(FileSend.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
   }
}
```

**Client Code:**

```
public class FileRecieve implements Runnable {
   Socket sock;
   String path;
   Date T;

   //private Date d2;
   FileRecieve(Socket s, String fname, Date d1) {
      sock = s;
      path = Main.Dpath + "/" + fname;
      T = d1;
   }

   public void run() {
      try {
         byte[] b = new byte[1024];
         int len = 0;
         long bytcount = 1024;

         File fp = new File(path);
         // RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile(fp,"r");

         RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile(fp, "rw");
         ra.seek(0);
         InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         while ((len = is.read(b, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            bytcount = bytcount + 1024;

            //decrypt
            ra.write(b, 0, len);
         }

         is.close();
         ra.close();
         sock.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Please help, many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should increment 'bytecount' by 'i', not 1024.

Comment: First of all, please make this code easier to read. Why are you nesting try/catch? Your exception handling in `run()` is also incorrect. You can use `FileInputStream` for reading, RandomAccessFile` is not really needed. `BufferedReader` is also to be used for character streams. The `bytecount` calculation is wrong.

Comment: I see no 'decrypt' action near your comment, or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a similar attempt at a Mutithreaded Client-Server [file downloader](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19113/multithreaded-client-server-file-downloading-application) app. You can check it out at code review. I have used the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package classes for the multithreading bit.